# Why `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` is still alive after dismiss the current viewController it belongs to

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I have a modalPresentedVC named `PlayerViewController` showing the music playing panel, the one includes some play, pause buttons and image cover.

And I implement `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` to let it continue to play next song when current one is complete. I notice that after I dismiss this `PlayerViewController` viewController, the audio play will go to the next song after the current is done. That is what I want, it is cool!

But I don't understand the things behind this. I think I have dismissed this ViewController, then the function `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` should not be accessed anyway from outside. But it still is called as I put `print("I'm alive")` in that method proving it.

So is that mean `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` could work outside its current viewController as build-in support? And we don't need any extra effort.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        goNextTrack()
        print("I'm alive")
        // omitted code
        updateTimeLabel()
    } else {
        fatalError("the audio doesn't finished playing successfully.")
    }
}

func goNextTrack() {
    if modelController.playMode == .cycle {
        self.position = (position + 1) % songs.count
        playSong()
    } else if modelController.playMode == .cycleOne {
        playSong()
    } else {
        songs.shuffle()
        playSong()
    }
}

func playSong() {
    let song = songs[position]
    guard let url = song.path else { return }
    AudioPlayer.shared.play(url: url)
    guard let player = AudioPlayer.shared.player else { return }

    // set player.delegate to current VC
    player.delegate = self 
    // omitted code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `playSong` you assign `self` as the `delegate` to `AudioPlayer`, so it retains a reference to your `PlayerViewController`, so even though you have dismissed it, the `AudioPlayer` keeps it alive, and calls `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` when it finishes playing the song.

Of course, the next natural question is, "why does the `AudioPlayer` remain alive?"  I'm pretty sure that's because behind the scenes it does the work of playing the song in an `@escaping` closure in a concurrent task.  To do its work that closure has to capture a reference to the player, keeping it alive.

Regarding getting duplicate `PlayerViewController` instances, that's because the `AudioPlayer` is a singleton and the `PlayerViewController` is being used as the `AudioPlayer`'s delegate, so the `PlayerViewController` is kept alive by the `AudioPlayer`.  Opening the view again spawns a new `PlayerViewController`, but the old one still exists in the `AudioPlayer`.

The solution is to refactor so `PlayerViewController` is no longer the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`.

So you move the methods for `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` conformance from your `PlayerViewController` to a separate object.  In the following code I assume `songs` is an array of `Song`, and that `modelController` is a `ModelController`, since those definitions aren't in the provided code.

In this case, I think the best candidate for the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` seems to be `AudioPlayer` itself.

Also since we're trying to decouple the `AudioPlayer` from the `PlayerViewController`, we still need a way for the `AudioPlayer` to communicate when a song ends so that it can update it's time label.  In preparation for that I declare a `PlayerListener` protocol (where in this case "listener" refers to the design pattern rather than listener of music).

```swift
protocol PlayerListener: class
{
    func receivePlayerMessage(_ message: AudioPlayer.Message)
}

@objc class AudioPlayer: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate
{
    // Singleton pattern
    static let shared = AudioPlayer()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer? = nil

    var songs: [Song] = []
    var position: Int = 0
    var modelController: ModelController? = nil
    
    enum Message
    {
        case songFinished
        case songStarted
    }
    
    private var listeners: [PlayerListener] = []
    
    private override init() {}
    
    func add(listener: PlayerListener) {
        listeners.append(listener)
    }
    
    func remove(listener: PlayerListener) {
        listeners.removeAll { $0 === listener }
    }
    
    func broadcast(message: Message) {
        listeners.forEach { $0.receivePlayerMessage(message) }
    }
    
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)
    {
        guard flag else {
            fatalError("the audio doesn't finished playing successfully.")
        }
        
        goNextTrack()
        print("I'm alive")
        broadcast(message: .songFinished)
    }
    
    func goNextTrack()
    {
        guard let playMode = modelController?.playMode else { return }
        
        switch playMode
        {
            case .cycle: position = (position + 1) % songs.count
            case .cycleOne:  break
            default: songs.shuffle()
        }
        
        playSong()
    }
    
    func playSong()
    {
        guard songs.indices.contains(position) else { return }
        
        let song = songs[position]
        guard let url = song.path else { return }
        
        play(url: url)
    }
    
    func play(url: URL)
    {
        do
        {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.delegate = self
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
            broadcast(message: .songStarted)
        }
        catch { print(error) }
    }
}
```

Remove `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` conformance from your `PlayerViewController`, and add conformance to `PlayerListener`.

Presumably it still needs to respond to `playSong()` and maybe `goNextTrack()` in response to UI elements.  Also since the `AudioPlayer` needs song data, you need to set that whenever your view loads/appears.  Because you mention re-using the view controller, let's do that in `viewDidAppear()`, though I question that approach - in my mind each view (or maybe view hierarchy) should have its own view controller instance. But that's just me.

```swift
// in PlayerViewController
    var position: Int
    {
        get { AudioPlayer.shared.position }
        set { AudioPlayer.shared.position = newValue }
    }
    
    func receivePlayerMessage(_ message: AudioPlayer.Message)
    {
        switch message
        {
            case .songStarted: updateTimeLabel()
            default: break
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear()
    {
        AudioPlayer.shared.songs = songs
        AudioPlayer.shared.modelController = modelController
        AudioPlayer.shared.add(listener: self)
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear() {
        AudioPlayer.shared.remove(listener: self)
    }

    func goNextTrack() {
        AudioPlayer.shared.goNextTrack()
    }

    func playSong() {
        AudioPlayer.shared.playSong()
    }
```

Now you have one player delegate for the life of the `AudioPlayer`.  When your view controller is dismissed it will not be kept alive (at least not by the `AudioPlayer`, and thus can be deinitialized and deallocated, so you don't end up with multiple instances of the view controller.

You did mention that you wanted to re-use the view controller, which is why we set `AudioPlayer` data in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.  I'm not sure that's a good idea, and is a separate question.  I'll address it somewhat in comments.

Comment: Thanks. I get your point on `retains a reference of self`. But my `AudioPlayer` is a Singleton pattern so it would be alive after the 1st initialization. I'm not using call back here. And 1 question, since this reference is not released, it may get some retain cycle later. Thus, is this the correct way to work with `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying ` or there is some better approach to do it?

Comment: Well, the main problem that stands out to me is that you set the delegate in the audio player every time you play the song.  You really should have a single delegate for the life of the player (same as you would for a NS/UIView's delegate).  So I would set it up separately.   If your `PlayerViewController` isn't also a singleton (which since you dismiss it, it seems it isn't), you might want to factor out the `AudioPlayer` delegate code into a separate object.

Comment: Making a separate `AudioPlayer` delegate object distinct from the `PlayerViewController` would also mean that when you dismiss the `PlayerViewController` it can be fully deinitialized and deallocated.  The way things are, *everything* that your `PlayerViewController` contains a strong reference to also remains alive even after you dismiss it, whether or not it has anything to do with the `AudioPlayer`.  That's almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I update my code per your answer, you could see in my answer below. And I get a question yet, may I help on this one? I'm really struggle on it.

Comment: `Making a separate... can be fully deinitialized and deallocated`, I agree with that. From my side, I need to let the audio player be alive across all the viewControllers and also in background, that is why I used Singleton.

Comment: Making a separate player delegate from your view controller would solve the problem of having a duplicate view controller instance, because it would deinitialize the old one on dismissal (or at least on the next iteration of the run loop), and create a new one when you open the view again.  I would think that logically that should be OK, but I don't know your app.   Do you *really* need to reuse the existing one, or do you only need to make sure that you have one at a time?

Comment: Well, I do need to reuse or say I want only one instance exist VC as it includes many ui elements, and has a timer too. Would you give me a small snippet showing how to make a separate player delegate? I really need some hint here.

Comment: Many UI elements shouldn't be a problem, unless load-time is an issue.   As for the timer... you mean for the time the song has been playing?  That can go in the `AudioPlayerDelegate` too.

Comment: If you *really* want to re-use the view controller, creating it programmatically rather than from Storyboard is easier.   Storyboard will tend to want to create each time you load the view... or depending on your app, maybe don't destroy the view.  Hide it instead, and update its contents for new model data appropriately before showing it again.

Comment: Perfect! I never thought it would be that kind detailed. Generally, I get your points. Next action is on me, the help is enough. Then I would go through it and implement it into my project. As a self-taught iOS coder, I could write quite of code, but when things get deeper and complicate, things like how to construct the code property, reused container view, align your data/state between all viewcontrollers will make me struggled.

Comment: BTW - I updated my answer to show creating a separate `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`.   But I notice that your player is `AudioPlayer` not `AVAudioPlayer`.  Is that your subclass of `AVAudioPlayer`? If so, you could simplify things a bit more by making the `AudioPlayer` its own delegate.

Comment: I didn't subclass to  my AudioPlayer class to `AVAudioPlayer`, instead using it directly `var player: AVAudioPlayer? `, you could see that line in my below answer code `var player: AVAudioPlayer?`

Comment: Ah ok.  In your `playSong` method it was just `AudioPlayer` not `AVAudioPlayer`, but maybe that's just a typo.

Comment: Oh, that is just the class name:) I name my audio manager class as `AudioPlayer`.

Comment: OK, in that case just make `AudioPlayer` be the `AVPlayerDelegate`, and now I see why you initialize it every time... I was forgetting about creating an `AVAudioPlayer` for every song.   Set the delegate in there.  I think I'm going to have to update my answer.

Comment: You don't need to cope with my code style as my code may not be in a good architecture. I have get your general idea about how to do this. Anyway, it is up to you.

Comment: Actually I was thinking that it would be simpler code if AudioPlayer were the AVPlayerDelegate delegate, and it makes sense for it to be.

Comment: I updated my answer to make `AudioPlayer` to be the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`.  It does simplify things a bit, so I also implemented the communication back to the view controller when a song ends so it can update the timer label.   But the AudioPlayer doesn't care if it's a view controller or any other type, as long as it conforms to `PlayerListener`.

Comment: I have refactor my code according to your answer. Use a protocol as intermediate and connect `PlayViewController` and `AudioManager`(I rename it for sake of misunderstand). And I invalidate timer inside this VC, thus there is no strong reference exist after dismiss, I prove this from `Debug memory graph`. Now there is only one PlayViewController instance alive or not, and all audio operations are moved into AudioManager. It makes my code a better architecture.

Comment: And that computed property `position` is a nice technique. It connect the position value in `AudioManager` to my VC, I don't need to retrieve it manually. Just one tiny typo in your code, this line should be `guard flag else`, then everything is cool!

Comment: `add(listener:` get a anchor/reference of viewController and save it into listeners array, that may allow the ability to extend to more viewController. This `$0.receivePlayerMessage(message)` is cool, we don't create an instance of viewController, but we could call a function inside it, though a protocol function.

Comment: I'm glad it helps!  You are correct that `guard !flag ...` should be `guard flag ...`.  I will fix it in my answer so it doesn't mislead others.  And yes the listener pattern (also called observer pattern) is very useful for decoupling objects.   Foundation's `NotificationCenter` could be used to do the same thing.  It uses a centralized version of the same pattern, but I find its often simpler to just make my own.

Comment: Yeah, yeah. This `observer pattern` is really a handy pattern, I'd like to use this technique more and more to improve my code proficiency. Because I want my app/code constructed like the real world practice code. But the quality content is too rare in the internet. I truly appreciate more deeper content like this!

Answer (score 0):

Update my code to give audio player a delegate only once. And add AudioPlayer API code.

Well, my really struggle here is `PlayerViewController` is a modalPresentedVC, which could be opened from different source. In my case, it could be opened from a tableView row click or a miniPlayer container(which is child view controller on top of the tabBar aka it could be seen cross the whole app pages).

But since there is a retain reference of `PlayerViewController`, so it is still alive even by dismissing. Then how could I open this same modalPresentedVC from the miniPlayer container, I mean when I click this miniPlayer container, this same `PlayerViewController` should be presented on the front again.

I try to used below code to open this VC again, but it seems I re-create a viewController instance, then I get two viewController instances now. How could I access the exist one?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Player") as? PlayerViewController else { return }
present(vc, animated: true)
```

```
func playSong() {
    let song = songs[position]
    guard let url = song.path else { return }
    AudioPlayer.shared.play(url: url)
    guard let player = AudioPlayer.shared.player else { return }

    // set player.delegate to current VC only once
    if player.delegate == nil {
        player.delegate = self
    }
    // omitted code
}
```

My AudioPlayer API

```
class AudioPlayer {
    // Singleton pattern
    static let shared = AudioPlayer()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    private init() {}
    
    func play(url: URL) {
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```